# Can I set polyline opacity in Android Google map API

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, opacity, google-polyline

I have draw polyline in my maps activity, but I have no idea to customize it like set up it opacity. I do need your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opacity should be added to the colour of polyline . Just add opacity at start of hex color value.

Eg if your colour is black i.e #0000

50 percent opacity colour will look like this
 #500000

Comment: So the #50 determined the opacity of the the color, isn't it?